# THREE.js html on top of renderer only works when components are dynamically generated

Tags: css, three.js

When using THREE.js in a website, whenever I make an element like this:

```
<p style='color:white;position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px;'></p>
```

the element *always* appears either before or after the renderer, not on top.
However, when I dynamically generate the component, like so:

```
var sun = document.createElement('div');
sun.className = 'sun';
sun.id = 'sun';
sun.style.right = window.innerWidth/2+'px';
sun.style.top = '100px';
sun.style.position = 'absolute';
```

It places it how I want it,

Any help appreciated

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not able to reproduce with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3enx25r6/. As you can see the `<p>` element is on top of the renderer's canvas.